# Removing Ubuntu boot option?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, wubi

I had installed Ubuntu inside Windows, then decided I didn't need it, so I tried to uninstall. It needed the disc, which I didn't have at the time, and I really needed the space, so I just deleted the installation folder. The option to boot into Ubuntu still shows up though, is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on **xp** or lower go to boot.ini and delete the entry for ubuntu. 
If you are on **vista** or higher

> run *cmd* as admin
>   type in *bcdedit*
>   go to the boot loader section
>   locate the os entry that you need to remove
>   copy the entry against **identifier**
>   type in *Bcdedit /delete {boot loader identifier}*
>
> braces are required

Answer (score 2):

The boot menu is not part of your [bios](/questions/tagged/bios) (as you had tagged your question), but displayed by the *boot manager* (sometimes "boot loader").

In Windows **XP and earlier**, the boot menu items are stored in **`\boot.ini`** of your system volume; you can edit the text file directly with Notepad, or run `bootcfg /delete /id entryid` from Command Prompt. (To list entry IDs, run `bootcfg`.)

In Windows **Vista and later**, the boot menu items are stored in **BCD** and editable using **`bcdedit`** from elevated Command Prompt, or such tools as EasyBCD.